# How do you change from omniscient narration to unreliable narration and vice versa in a comic book without speech balloons?

Tags: creative-writing, comics, narration

How do you change from omniscient narration to unreliable narration and vice versa in a comic book without speech balloons? I am guessing you need to put square speech balloons, to switch from omniscient to unreliable, but I am wondering if it can be done without square speech balloons, because I feel using these speech balloons is telling and not showing. So is it possible to do that without speech balloons, or not, and what would you suggest?

Comment: I've seen it done loads of times in comics.  Early Superman/Batman comics (Circa 2007 ish) do this frequently.

Comment: Your question is unclear in many respects. First, omniscient narration isn't the opposite of unreliable narration. The opposite of omniscient narration is limited narration, and the opposite of unreliable narration is reliable relation. Both can be combined in multiple ways: You can have a reliable omniscient narrator, an unreliable omniscient narrator, an unreliable limited narrator and a reliable limited narrator. So in what way is your narrator reliable or unreliable and omniscient or limited, and why does that change during the narration?

Comment: Also, you probably aren't talking about speech baloons but captions. Speech baloons are usually round and have a pointer that points to the person that is speaking. Captions are usually rectangular and contain narration. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_comics_terminology. I think your question would become more clear if you gave an example of the story you are trying to write and what effect you want to achieve.